# equality cheking in python

Tags: python, if-statement, equality

My program is as follows:

```
print h   # h value is printed as h1
if h=='h1':
    servpro()
else:
    hostpro()
```

I am seeing `h` value as `h1`.  But there is a problem in the if condition. Even though `h` is printed as `h1`, the `else` block is getting executed.  What is the problem with my program?

Comment: `h` isn't `'h1'`. Print out `repr(h)` and see what the actual value is. There might be a space in it that you cannot see.

Comment: Need to change `else` to `else:`.

Comment: If what @Blender says is true, you could change it to `if h.strip() == 'h1':` to get the results you desire.

Comment: @SethMMortonI tried with that.Then it is showing "Host" object has no attribute strip.Should I import some module for that?

Comment: Show us an output sample, please.

Comment: I have given if h.strip() == 'h1'.But it is showing error.Attribute error.'Host' object has no attribute 'strip' @GamesBrainiac

Comment: well, then it's a `Host` object, and not the string `h1`.

Comment: @roippi Thanks.But now how can I compare h with h1?

Comment: Most likely `if h.name == 'h1':`

Comment: Is `h1` another Host object, or do you want to compare it to the string literal `'h1'`?

Comment: can you post in the code the definition of `h`? did you define it ? can you post also `h.__class__` and `h.__class__.__name__`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, you can find the `field` in the `Host` object that holds `'h1'` and do

```
if h.field == 'h1':
    servpro()
else:
    hostpro()
```

You can also try

```
if repr(h) == 'h1':
    servpro()
else:
    hostpro()
```

repr calls a magic method **repr** of h, which gives a string containing the representation of h

Answer (score 0):

To understand better why the results of the comparison you are doing are the way they are , look at [Python's data model](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html), and specifically read about the `object.__eq__`  and `object.__cmp__` methods. Of course you can override these methods. [See examples.](http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/32837.html)

Answer (score 0):

Python's print statement displays the string representation of an object. So if it prints as 'h1' (without the quotes), you could try testing if that is the object's string representation :

```
if str(h) == 'h1':
    servpro()
else:
    hostpro()
```